# How to select a common attribute from 2 different tables, with the highest appearence of a mutual attribute?

Tags: sql, select

So i have a table "accident", and the attribute "pess_segura" which is the number of an ensured person envolved in an accidente.

I also have a table "acid_pess" which has 2 relevant attributes for this problem "accident" and "pessoa", this table refers to people envolved in accidents that are not ensured (they were involved in an accident but they were not driving).
So i want to select the accident with most people envolved.

These are the relevant tables for this exercise

```
create table person(
    n_pess bigint not null,
    nif integer not null,
    cart_cond varchar(15),
    pais_cart_cond varchar(30),
    doc_id varchar(15) not null,
    pais_doc_id varchar(30) not null,
    nome varchar(80) not null,
    primary key(n_pess),
    unique(nif),
    unique(cart_cond),
    unique(doc_id)
);

create table ensurance(
    apolice bigint not null,
    ensured bigint not null,
    veiculo bigint not null,
    datai date not null,
    dataf date not null,
    cobertura numeric(10,2) not null,
    primary key(apolice),
    unique(ensured, veiculo),
    foreign key (ensured) references person(n_pess),
    foreign key (veiculo) references veiculo(n_veic)
);  

create table accident(
    n_acid bigint not null,
    pess_segura bigint not null,
    veic_seguro bigint not null,
    data date not null,
    local varchar(255) not null,
    descr text not null,
    primary key(n_acid),
    unique(n_acid, veic_seguro),
    foreign key (pess_segura,veic_seguro) references ensurance(ensured, veiculo)
);

create table acid_pess(
    accident bigint not null,
    person bigint not null,
    veiculo bigint not null,
    descr text not null,
    primary key(accident, person),
    foreign key (accident) references accident(n_acid),
    foreign key (person) references person(n_pess),
    foreign key (accident, veiculo) references accident(n_acid, veic_seguro)
);
```

I want to select the n_acid(number of the accident) that had the most people envolved.

Comment: Can you please post the script you are trying with to achieve your goal? Also please tag Database you are using.

Comment: @Miguel Ribeiro if there is more than one do you need all or just one?